# Shell Script Issue can't find the total size

Tags: linux, shell

I have created a shell script that would read a text file and will find the size of the file. The problem is its not giving the total file size.

For example when I execute `./sushant7.sh` I get:

```
Size is 4.0K    lesurvey1
Size is 4.0K    tbbsr11d1def
Size is 4.0K    tbbsr11d1def
```

I want to get `12k` as total which I am not able to.

My script is

```
FILE1=/home/dev/sushanttest

cd $FILE1

while read file
do
    echo "Size is ` du -ha  $file`"

done < /home/dev/sushanttest/listing.txt
```

Comment: Note that if you use `-h` it will be sometimes MB, others KB.... It is better to use `-BK` to kilobytes, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
xargs du -ch < /home/dev/sushanttest/listing.txt | grep total
```

This gives all the files as an argument to a single `du` call. If you iterate yourself over the files, you'll have to sum up yourself.

Comment: Thanks that helped but when i execute the script i get three results rather just getting one.                                           12K     total
12K     total
12K     total

Comment: I figured it out. i did  xargs du -ch $file. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make use of the `-b` switch as well to `du` to print out the size in bytes. For example:

`$ du -cb FILE_GLOB | grep total | awk '{print $1}'`